# Setting up a SPARQL Endpoint with other permissions than 'SPARQL' user

Tags: sparql, endpoint, virtuoso

I've set up another virtual directory within Virtuoso Conductor in order to access a second SPARQL endpoint through another port.
My question: Why can I only choose 'dba' user to make the endpoint run? Is there a way to grant other permissions than these from user 'SPARQL' to my second endpoint?
I know how to grant/revoke permissions to/from 'SPARQL' but is there a possibility to match the new endpoint to a user e.g. called 'SPARQL2'??
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no possibility to map SPARQL endpoints to users with different permissions.
This guidelines show what's possible at the moment:

http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideSPARQLEndpoints
and
http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql.html#rdfsupportedprotocolendpoint